# Разделение обращения в деловом письме whitespace'ами

Tags: пунктуация, письменность, деловой-язык

Возник вопрос о правильном составлении делового письма, например, при деловой переписке по электронной почте, как правильно обособлять конструкции внутри письма? Какой из приведенных двух вариантов считается правильным? Внутренние рассуждения среди меня и моих друзей привели к тому, что мы разделилесь на два фланга.

Вариант 1:

```
Здравствуйте, Иван Иванович.    
Спасибо за ваше письмо.    

Далее текст по существу.
```

Вариант 2:

```
Здравствуйте, Иван Иванович.

Спасибо за ваше письмо.    

Далее текст по существу.
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

VER2: Имелась в виду разница отсуплений между строками.

Comment: Не вижу разницы, варианты одинаковы.

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: Какое отношение этот буллшит имеет за **русский язык**?  *Мода* на оформление бумажек меняется 150 раз на дню, самые модные и последние дури преподают на курсах делопроизводителей обучающимся. А конкретным деловарам на ужимки  прыжки обезьян вообще накласть

Answer (score 1):

Обращения в деловой переписке обособляются по общим правилам - запятыми, на конце и точка, и восклицательный знак корректны.

А вот по сути Ваше письмо похоже больше на личное, в деловом лучше оформить так:"Уважаемый Иван Иванович, Ваше письмо получил, спасибо". Можно обойтись без приветствия "Здравствуйте", но можно и оставить, а вот "уважаемый",Вы, Ваш желательны.

Comment: идея в том, что вместо "спасибо за ваше письмо" может быть любой вступительный текст, отсылающий либо к самому факту отправки письма или к каким-то другим вещам из прошлой переписки, котороые, при этом, не являются основой всего письма.

Comment: Да никаких отступов, увеличения интервалов между строками не надо. Всё как обычно - с красной строки